# Missing new lines in Bash in passing function to variable

Tags: bash

Why in this case doesnt generate new lines in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

function sample() {
    local DATA=""
    DATA="test1"$'\n'
    DATA="${DATA}test2"$'\n'
    echo ${DATA}
}


DATA=$(sample)
printf "%s" "${DATA}"
```

Comment: Replace `echo ${DATA}` with `echo "${DATA}"`.

Comment: It does generate newlines; you are throwing them away by not quoting your parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0):

`$DATA` is expanded, and all whitespace (including newlines) are used for word-splitting, before `echo` ever runs. You should *always* quote parameters expansions.

```
sample() {
    local DATA=""
    DATA="test1"$'\n'
    DATA="${DATA}test2"$'\n'
    echo "${DATA}"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You must use the **-e** option of **echo** for it to interpret the **\n** character:

```
echo -e "${DATA}"
```

Comment: There are no `\n` digraphs in `DATA`, only literal newlines, due to the `$'...'` quoting.